# Merge two columns in 2 dataframes depending on matching pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, data.table

I have two dataframes

Df1

```
Col1 Name Col3
ALL1 10 OP
ALL2 20 IO
ALL2 20 YU
ALL2 20 RT
ALL3 20 YU
ALL3 90 YU
ALL4 98 IU
```

DF2

```
   Col1bis Col2
    ALL1 OKI
    ALL2 OP
    ALL3 I
    ALL4 LOP
```

The expected result is:

DF2

```
  Col1bis Col2 Name
    ALL1 OKI 10
    ALL2 OP 20
    ALL3 I 90
    ALL4 LOP 98
```

and I would like to add the column `Name` to the df2 to which correspond to the same pattern in Col1 and Col1bis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF2)[DF1, Name := Name, on = .(Col1bis = Col1)]
DF2
#   Col1bis Col2 Name
#1:    ALL1  OKI   10
#2:    ALL2   OP   20
#3:    ALL3    I   90
#4:    ALL4  LOP   98
```

---

Or in `base R` with `match`

```
DF2$Name <- DF1$Name[match(DF2$Col1bis, DF1$Col1)]
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("ALL1", "ALL2", "ALL2", "ALL2", "ALL3", 
"ALL3", "ALL4"), Name = c(10L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 90L, 98L), 
    Col3 = c("OP", "IO", "YU", "RT", "YU", "YU", "IU")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

DF2 <- structure(list(Col1bis = c("ALL1", "ALL2", "ALL3", "ALL4"), Col2 = c("OKI", 
"OP", "I", "LOP")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is merge or "join" your datasets, here are three of the most common approaches:l. First here's the data I test this with.

```
# Dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(
  V1 = letters[1:10], 
  V2 = rnorm(10, 0, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(
  V1 = letters[c(1,4,6)],
  V3 = rnorm(3, 0, 1))
```

Approach one is base R using the `merge()` function which is given the two data frames and a variable by which it should join the data.

```
# Base R
merge(df1, df2, by = "V1")
```

The next is using the tidyverse packages and a pipe, `%>%`, select df1 first and then using the `right_join()` function, one of many different join functions in those packages.

```
# Tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% right_join(df2, by = "V1")
```

The final option is the one I'd use, from the data.table package. The joining variable(s) here is given by `on = ...`.

```
# Data.table
library(data.table)
# - convert to data.tables
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
# - join
df1[df2, on = "V1"]
```

Note that if you built/read your data in as a data.table (using `data.table()` and `fread()` respectively) you could skip the convert step.

Comment: sure, we could chat at some time

Comment: Thanks- I'll try to find a window of opportunity where, you know, there isn't a 1 year old sat on my face